Why did so many 30s movies feature posh upper class characters?
I've watched 50 of them on my list so far and I've noticed a pattern here, especially in screwball comedies and musicals. I'd be more interested in seeing how regular middle class families were portrayed but I imagine there wasn't much of a middle class during the Depression.

It might help if you gave some examples.  I think this is an interesting question if people take the time to research an answer.  I suspect it might partially come from the fact that before movies there was only live theater, a medium that is expensive as a consumer and people often want to see 'themselves' represented on the stage - and I'm sure a lot of screenwriting at the time was done by playwrights (or aspiring playwrights).  I imagine that there is a bit of inertia here.

I'm sure there was plenty of a middle class even during the depression - by which I mean the people identify with the middle class, even if many of the jobs didn't exist and they were forced to take whatever work was available.

Also (and this is why examples may be good) are these 'screwball comedies' lampooning the posh / rich characters?  Or are they protagonists?

Without seeing your list it's hard to know if there is some selection bias going on here. I can think of several movies off the top of my head that featured middle class or lower families: the "Andy Hardy" series, "You Can't Take it With You", The Chaplin films with the Little Tramp. There WAS a considerable middle class during the depression (the peak unemployment rate was 25%), and an even larger group that had recently been in the middle class.

@CharlesE.Grant - I actually felt like this was a good question. It's pretty easy to find the top box office draws of the 1930s and mark them as "About posh people doing posh things" or "not about posh people doing posh things" and then analyse whether the majority of theatrical productions were about the former rather than the latter.

Going to the cinema to watch a movie has always been an escapist form of entertainment.  It has been other things too, but for the majority of the ticket-buying public in the USA, it has been a way to escape daily life for a while.
During the Great Depression (1929 to 1939-41 according to Wikipedia), the population suffered from the effects of poverty, and dreamed of the kind of life enjoyed by the merchant class and the wealthy.  I.e., "posh upper class" people.  As cinema audiences, they bought tickets to films that gave them escape into these dreams of leisure and wealth.  The movie studios responded by making lots of those films.

I do think this is probably part of it - but there's not a lot of source for what you write here other than 'it makes sense'.  Are there any other factors too?

IMO, not just dreams of what their own lives could be like if they were posh and upper-class, but in the case of comedies, a way of mollifying the masses by making the posh, upper-class something to laugh at... something even to deride. Entertainment isn't just a way for people to escape their problems, it's also a tool to distract people from their problems. After all, if you're laughing at the character, you're not laughing at the actor.

By definition, Screwball comedies featured very rich people doing silly things. Even today we like to laugh (or gawk) at the very rich (see Real Housewives) so that we don't feel so bad about not having all the luxuries that they have. Also, starting in mid-1934 the Hays Office started strictly enforcing the Production Code, so it was tougher for filmmakers to explicitly critique rich industrialists or debutantes.
During the 1930s, Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer and Paramount were the two biggest movie studios in Hollywood, and both were already known for making glossy movies about the upper class since the 1920s. On the other hand, Warner Brothers specialized in making hard-hitting critiques of current events "ripped from the headlines", so their films were more about middle-class and lower-class people. As a general rule, MGM and Paramount would never make a film about a social issue of lower class people like I Was a Fugitive On a Chain Gang (1932), but this was just one of many at Warner Brothers.
The same year, Universal made a low-budget film with Pat O'Brien called Laughter in Hell (1932), which was just as hard-hitting about chain gangs, but it lost money even with its small budget. People were not interested in the struggles of the lower class that much. As a general rule, audiences preferred to get their minds off their troubles. Studios did feel more comfortable making films about middle-class and lower-class characters that lived in the country, where life was (allegedly) simpler.
From 1929 through mid-1934, there were many more films about poverty and joblessness, as many pre-Code films showed women sleeping their way to riches or men using dishonest means (like gangsters) to either survive or get to the top. But with the Code in effect, law-breakers had to be punished by the end of the film. Films like It Happened One Night (1934) or My Man Godfrey (1936) contrast the difference between poor and rich, and the poor can show the rich a thing or two because the rich don't have a clue.

Carole Lombard and William Powell in My Man Godfrey (1936)
Although it may be strange that so many films from the 1930s don't reference the Depression, but think about what modern society has been though during three years of COVID-19. How many films or TV shows reference that tough time, even though everybody (rich or poor) had struggles during this time?

Gee thanks! I have a B.S. in TV-Film from the University of Texas, I've written for Classic Images magazine and I've been collecting movie stills from the silent era through the 1930s for decades.

Probably best to disclose your affiliation when posting pictures.
